# Trouble getting layout to work when XS and when larger than XS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have multiple panels displayed with lists of checkboxes for the user to check and submit for search results.  When the screen is SM and larger, my layout works.  When the size is XS, the layout does not work.  I am looking for help to get my layout working when XS size.

When the size is SM and larger, I want 3 checkbox controls per line.
When the screen size is XS, I want 1 checkbox control per line.

I can get my SM and larger layout to work, as shown in my bootply link, but I can not get that layout to work with a proper XS layout.

Also, my layout looks ugly, if you know how to make this look nice, please share. Your input is welcome.

Link to bootply
http://www.bootply.com/BOvZe8VVfw#

Comment: Try using Bootstrap's checkbox markup; see "Checkboxes and radios" under http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

Comment: Thanks.  I've been chasing this as a column problem.  Doing the inline checkbox did fix my formatting.